# How to create a search using multiple variables and to make them not mandatory

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticjs

I have this code :

```
let jobs = await client.search({
      index: 'something',
      type: 'doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match: {
                  title: `test`
                }
              },
              {
                match: {
                  desc: `test`
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

for me to make a search I need to add a title and a desc , but I wish to search even if one is not present, meaning I want either title or desc, does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, instead of must we can write should, and it will work:

```
let jobs = await client.search({
      index: 'something',
      type: 'doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            should: [
              {
                match: {
                  title: `test`
                }
              },
              {
                match: {
                  desc: `test`
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```